# How to Change Hudson Default Interface Language

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I'm running hudson.war through the command line. It launches the interface in my default language, portuguese. How can I change to english?

Answer (score 10):

Depends on what you want:

If you want to change the language only for yourself, change the browser settings.

If you want to change it for everyone, there is a [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Locale+Plugin) for that.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you have to change browser language.

Chrome (Mac) > Preferences > Under the Hood > Web Content > Languages and Spell-checker Settings...
Internet Explorer > Tools > Internet Options > General > Languages

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins shows the Web interface in whatever language your web browser asks. If you are not happy with the language, you need to change your web browser settings.