# Change the language of the console output in jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins, console

At the moment I'm using Jenkins on a German Windows. My Firefox is set to english, but the output console from jenkins is german. how I can change the language into english for the console?
Thank you ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Change Hudson Default Interface Language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659578/how-to-change-hudson-default-interface-language). Or see [Change-hudsons-language](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Change-hudsons-language-td1017648.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has also puzzled me.

Setting the language of the browser does change the language of the front-end interface for the user.

However, the question is: How to ensure that the language of the console output is set to english?

My browser language is set to english, and I see Jenkins in english as expected when logging in to the front-end, but I still see danish translations in the console output.

The reason must be that Jenkins back-end, which generate the console output, uses the language of the server which hosts Jenkins. Try changing the language settings on the server.