# Change language of jenkins console output

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins' web interface language is in english and web browser language is also is in English. But still I see my console output in Japanese. 
I found one [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626684/change-the-language-of-the-console-output-in-jenkins) question like this. But still not able to resolve.

My server has centos (UTC time zone) and Jenkins version is : 2.36

My system's language:

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/i18n 
#LANG="ja_JP.Shift-JIS"
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
```

Please suggest if I have to check anything else.

**If possible please share commands/snapshots to get it done**.

[image: Here is the console output]

Thanks.

Comment: Console output will be using the backend server locale.

Comment: Try change `$LANG` for your Jenkins process.

Comment: Is this is a programming question?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the machine you installed your Jenkins is English local, and not a localized version of the OS.

Answer (score 1):

**Under Manage Jenkins > Configure System there should be a "Locale" section.**

Here you can enter the **"Default Language"**: this should be a language code or locale code like "fr" (for French), or "de_AT" (German, in Austria).

This value will be used by the system, for example, for messages that are printed to the log during a build (assuming that the Jenkins features and plugins that you're using have been translated into the specified language).

To additionally force this language on all users, overriding their browser language, you can check the **"Ignore browser preference and force this language to all users"** option.

Comment: I found locale but there is no option of **Ignore browser preference and force this language to all users**
Still console output is like this :

`ユーザーadminが実行
masterでビルドします。 ワークスペース: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/DataHandler/workspace`

Comment: Ah ok I have one, hmmm... I see if I can find something else

Answer (score 0):

Check if it works when you execute a batch script in jenkins as one of your first build steps. In this script, you could try to change the codepage like documented here: https://superuser.com/questions/387569/how-do-i-permantly-set-the-command-prompt-codepage-in-windows-7

> chcp 1252

Comment: PO is using CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this Jenkins plugin for control the language of Jenkins

[Locale Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Locale+Plugin)